# How to get mouse to work in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have an installation of FreeBsd in VMWare workstation.  I installed GNOME on the system, so It has a gui.  However, none of my mouse movements or clicks are regestering.  How do I fix this?  The keyboard works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it didn't work.
I reinstalled FreeBSD, and when I was reinstalling it, there was an option for a plug-in called "Moused"  If you select that plug-in on installation, it works fine.